# Rox Video Xamarin Forms Ios Not working

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I am using Rox video plugin to play videos in Xamarin forms iOS.  It plays the video perfectly however if I change device orientation or change to a different screen the video continues to play in the background. I can hear the audio continuing.  When returning to the video player view I it loads a new version of the video up.

Can anyone with experience in the Rox Video plugin assist? or offer a free alternative to this plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I searched the issue list of `RoxXamarinVideo` on github but found nothing about your problem.

I suggest you use [FormsNativeVideoPlayer](https://github.com/xamarin/customer-success-samples/tree/master/samples/Xamarin.Forms/FormsNativeVideoPlayer), it seems to have a great support on orientation changes.

[image]

Comment: Check the code, the code up there is not compiling from VS for Mac.